# How to remove date from an array having a same year, month and day with higher time?

Tags: php, date

In PHP how to remove dates from an array having a same year, month and day with higher times?

```
array(7) { 
    [0]=> string(19) "2012-06-11 08:30:49" 
    [1]=> string(19) "2012-06-11 08:03:54" 
    [2]=> string(19) "2012-05-26 23:04:04" 
    [3]=> string(19) "2012-05-27 08:30:00" 
    [4]=> string(19) "2012-06-08 08:30:55" 
    [5]=> string(19) "2012-06-08 08:31:12" 
    [6]=> string(19) "2012-06-08 08:55:24"
}
```

Will remove `array[0],array[5],array[6]`

Output:

```
('2012-06-11 08:03:54',''2012-05-26 23:04:04','2012-05-27 08:30:00','2012-06-08 08:30:55')
```

OR

```
'2012-06-11 08:03:54'
'2012-05-26 23:04:04'
'2012-05-27 08:30:00'
'2012-06-08 08:30:55'
```

In other words, I only want the earliest date on distinct days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array( 
    "2012-06-11 08:30:49" ,
    "2012-06-11 08:03:54" ,
    "2012-05-26 23:04:04" ,
    "2012-05-27 08:30:00" ,
    "2012-06-08 08:30:55" ,
    "2012-06-08 08:31:12" ,
    "2012-06-08 08:55:24"
);

$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $item){
    $item_array = explode(" ", $item);
    $date = $item_array[0];
    $time = $item_array[1];
    if(!isset($new_array[$date]) || $time < $new_array[$date])
        $new_array[$date] = $time;
}

$final = array();

foreach($new_array as $key => $value){
    $final[] = $key . ' ' . $value;
}

print_r($final);
```

Comment: Hi @Dev your code helps a lot. Many thanks to you. Elo from Phils.

Answer (score 1):

```
$filtered = array();
foreach ($array as $time) {
    $day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($time));
    if (!isset($filtered[$day]) || strtotime($filtered[$day]) > strtotime($time)) {
        $filtered[$day] = $time;
    }
}
```

Comment: If "higher times" is a hard requirement, then yes. You could also check if `$filtered[$day]` already exists and compare before replacing it.

Comment: @Gordon .. final output is tricky he wants `'2012-06-11 08:03:54'` followed by a lower date `'2012-05-26 23:04:04` then a higher date agan `'2012-06-08 08:30:55'` ... what sorting format is this ???

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `usort`

```
$array = array( 
    "2012-06-11 08:30:49" ,
    "2012-06-11 08:03:54" ,
    "2012-05-26 23:04:04" ,
    "2012-05-27 08:30:00" ,
    "2012-06-08 08:30:55" ,
    "2012-06-08 08:31:12" ,
    "2012-06-08 08:55:24"
);


usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = strtotime($a);
    $b = strtotime($b);
    return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a > $b) ? - 1 : 1);
});

$list = array();
foreach ( $array as $time ) {
    $day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($time));
    if (! array_key_exists($day, $list))
        $list[$day] = $time;
}

var_dump($list);
```

Output

```
array
  '2012-06-11' => string '2012-06-11 08:30:49' (length=19)
  '2012-06-08' => string '2012-06-08 08:55:24' (length=19)
  '2012-05-27' => string '2012-05-27 08:30:00' (length=19)
  '2012-05-26' => string '2012-05-26 23:04:04' (length=19)
```

Comment: @Baba, your code doesn't return earliest date. For example, for the date '2012-06-11' the time '08:03:54' is the earliest, and your code produces '08:30:49'.

Comment: All he needs to do is sort first instead @bhovhannes

Comment: I agree, @Baba, the loop should go after sorting, my answer also is using the same approach

Comment: @Elo .. you can not accept 2 questions at the same time .... You accepted someone else too which invalidated mine

Answer (score 1):

The one way is to loop through sorted array eliminating higher time values when the dates remain constant. Below is working code:

```php
echo '<pre>';
$in = array(
    '2012-06-11 08:30:49',
    '2012-06-11 08:03:54',
    '2012-05-26 23:04:04',
    '2012-05-27 08:30:00',
    '2012-06-08 08:31:12',
    '2012-06-08 08:30:55',
    '2012-06-08 08:55:24',
);
var_dump($in);

$out = $in;
sort($out, SORT_STRING);
for($i=count($out)-2; $i>=0; --$i)
{
    list($d1, $t1) = explode(' ', $out[$i+1]);
    list($d2, $t2) = explode(' ', $out[$i]);
    if($d1 == $d2 && $t2 <= $t1) //same date and lower time
    {
        unset($out[$i+1]);
    }
}

var_dump($out);
echo '</pre>';
```

If the order of elements is not important, this approach will be fast enough, because it is using php's `sort()` function and the only time consuming thing which is done in code is looping through array, which takes O(n) time.

Also, if you don't need to preserve original array, you can replace `$out` with `$in` everywhere and drop the `$out=$in` line. That will improve memory usage, since additional array will not be created.